# Openrowset syntax issues in Azure Synapse

Tags: azure, t-sql, azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse

I'm using Azure synapse query editor to run the below query,
This is also an example provided in the Azure documentation

```
SELECT
    nyc.filename() AS [filename]
    ,COUNT_BIG(*) AS [rows]
FROM  
    OPENROWSET(
        BULK '../userdata1.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage,
    FORMAT_TYPE = PARQUET
    ) nyc
GROUP BY nyc.filename();
```

But it always throws

> Parse error at line: 5, column: 5: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'.

But, I was able to successfully run the Create statement with full schema and perform select queries on the external table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dbo.userdata1 (
    [registration_dttm] nvarchar(100) NULL,
    [id]                decimal(38,0) NULL,
    [first_name]        nvarchar(100) NULL,
    [last_name]         nvarchar(100) NULL,
      |
      |
      |
)
WITH (
    LOCATION='../userdata1.parquet',
    DATA_SOURCE = AzureStorage,
    FILE_FORMAT=parquet_file_format
);
```

Select @@Version --

> Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse - 10.0.15225.0 Sep 8 2020 20:17:38 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation

Please correct me if anything wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "AS" when you assign nyc to the rowset:

SELECT
...
FROM
OPENROWSET(
...
) **AS** nyc
GROUP BY nyc.filename();

Comment: Thanks for the response @joel-cochran , also I went through the docs and understood this query only works in Azure Synapse SQL On-Demand, am I correct ??

Comment: Yes, this syntax is for SQL On-demand (SOD). In SQL Pool, you would use Polybase (external tables) as you shared in your post. If this response solved your problem, please accept it as the answer.